# How can i do operations while entering data in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to import data composed of 10 documents into kibana using dev tools. while doing this I want to edit data by subtracting timestamp between two different documents grouped according to the id. How can I do this using DevTools in kibana?

```
id         timestamp

1          1592833114

1          1592833192

2          1592833302

2          1592833400
```

I want this data indexed into elastic search like:

```
id  time

1    78 i.e(1592833192 - 1592833114)

2    98 i.e(1592833400 - 1592833302)
```

Comment: So, each line is an individual log line?

Comment: yes, each line is a document I want to use for visualization @Gibbs

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as it is two different log lines.

There are two options you can do.

1. At the time of ingestion using logstash
2. You have to change log line to add data in single log line.

You can refer [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-calculate-time-difference-between-2-log-lines-for-a-unique-id/155870/2), [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/compare-fields-in-two-documents/116548)

I will add few more references.

Please let me know if I need to consider more variables related to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, no i've got it. I'll be using data i want to subtract in the same log line! Thanks